# How to prevent sending duplicate entries?

Tags: sql, ajax, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic application in which I have a table in a Local database where I store lat long and timestamp, the database gets updated whenever there is an update in the location and in turn an api is triggered, on success of that api the entry in the table is deleted.
suppose I got another entry before the success of the previous one, the api will get triggered with both the entries and the central db will be populated with duplicate values of the first entry.
How can I prevent this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well it depends how your doing that, are you using threads ? , but you should add a condition or checking in application level when you send a request , once the request is finish you can send another one

Comment: add relevant code which describe the problem. Thats what people here understand better and suggest solutions.

Comment: A typical issue with modern client-server. Modify the local table to include a column indicating that the new location is 'pending' or 'committed'. Set to indicate pending when you send to the server and subsequently to 'committed' when server indicates success. Every time you get a new location change to post, check the a 'pending' or 'committed' record and if either are present ignore it as it is already processed.[PS. good question but likely to get shut down as too broad - provide a cut-down example next time.]